# How to take panaroma shot using my Nokia C6?

Tags: panorama, cameraphones, nokia

I have a Nokia c6. I want to shoot wide angle panoramas shots, without using a special lens. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could search your OVI app store for  [Nokia Panorama](http://www.themobileindian.com/news/7105_Top-5-Camera-apps-for-Symbian_2), or alternatively you could search the app store for other camera application which has the panorama function

Answer (score 1):

You take a series of photos that cover the area you want to cover and then stitch them together.  This is actually the way most panoramas and 360 degree images are produced.  (When they need it all captured in a single moment, typically multiple cameras are used.)

You can use a photo-stitching package like Microsoft ICE (free and available for Windows) or you can use an app for your phone that you could probably find on your app store.  Make sure to include some overlap and try to keep consistent exposure between shots to get the best looking result.